# Facebook app in tab, how to create a link/button to like the page

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm creating a facebook app with the PHP sdk, which is displayed in a tab. It's for a contest, and I check if the user likes the page. If he does, he gets to see the contest immediately, if he doesn't, he should see a custom like button, to like the page.

I've been searching for a long time and haven't found out how I can create a custom button/link to like the page. If anyone could point me into the right direction, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You can’t. Use the like button that FB provides and put it into your app – or let users just like the page by the like button that is shown on top of the page anyways.

Comment: Is there really no way? I could swear I've seen it before...

Comment: The like button FB provides can not be customized apart from the options they offer – and their policies forbid to try and do that as well. What you might have seen are just custom buttons that use the Open Graph like action (og.like) – but that works for Open Graph objects only, not for native FB pages.